# One Android application's activity running in the process of another; what does `android:multiprocess` do?

Tags: android, android-activity, multiprocess

### Big picture

I have two Android application, `Host` and `Guest`. I am trying to run an activity from `Guest` such that it immediately opens an activity in `Host`. The intention is that launching the `Guest` app should run in the `Host`, but appear to be running as the `Guest` (i.e. the user should, to all intents and purposes, not know of the host's existence despite it doing the heavy lifting for the guest).

This question is about getting that `Host` activity to run in the process belonging to `Host`.

(*why* I want to do this is probably out of scope for this question, but it's definitely something I want to do).

### What I have tried before

To start with, it was thought that process separation from the rest of the `Host` activities was enough.

To do this, the process was named in the `<activity>` element in the manifest.

```
<activity android:name=".MainHostActivity" android:process="host.process" />
```

For two reasons, this proved to be problematic:

- it kind've worked, but it gets very hacky and messy in the face of multiple guests.
- the standard Android tools to enable the user to manage the apps don't work (e.g. swiping away the app from the Recent Apps List).
- the process names have to be known at compile time.

### `android:multiprocess`

Looking at the AndroidManifest.xml documentation, I have found [this activity attribute](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#multi) which seems helpful:

> `android:multiprocess`
>
> Whether an instance of the activity can be launched into the process of the component that started it — `true` if it can be, and `false` if not. The default value is `false`.
>
> Normally, a new instance of an activity is launched into the process of the application that defined it, so all instances of the activity run in the same process. However, if this flag is set to `true`, instances of the activity can run in multiple processes, allowing the system to create instances wherever they are used (provided permissions allow it), something that is almost never necessary or desirable.

My reading of this documentation is that this could be what I am looking for. I would prefer it to say "the activity *is* launched" rather than "the activity *can be* launched" "into the process of the component that started it".

Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be the case. Launching `Host` activity from `Guest` always ends up with different processes, as measured by `android.os.Process.myPid()`.

I have put up a [pair of dummy applications](https://github.com/jhugman/android-multiprocess) which should show what I am trying to do:

- install `Host`.
- install and run `Guest`
- The activity launched will have a number (the pid of the guest) and three buttons. Clicking on either of the first two should launch a second activity. The second activity should show the same number as the first, and `true`, which shows that the host and guest are running in the same process.

Unfortunately, this does not appear to be the case.

#### TL;DR

How do I get the activities from the different activities to run in the same process owned by the the caller application?

What does `android:multiprocess` on the `activity` element actually do?

**Edit**:
I have a [minimal example](https://github.com/jhugman/android-multiprocess) which should show what I'm wanting. Success is when the `MainHostActivity` shows the same number as `MainGuestActivity`. The number is `android.os.Process.myPid()`.

- [Github link to minimal example](https://github.com/jhugman/android-multiprocess)
- [Stackoveflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832542/one-android-applications-activity-running-in-the-process-of-another-what-does)

Comment: You don't, unless you intentionally and specifically want to dump the entire design intent of Android and try to force things the hard way yourself behind the scenes.  Android is built on the idea of interprocess communication, meaning that a thread of *execution* can cross into another *process* and back again.

Comment: "The intention is that launching the Guest app should run in the Host, but appear to be running as the Guest" -- you might wish to explain what "appear to be" means.

Comment: Are both Guest and Host signed with the same certificate?

Comment: @FunkTheMonk - no. Currently, I can change both Guest and Host. Later, making changes to the Guest will be harder. I can always change the Host.

Comment: @CommonsWare - the host is a runtime. The guest are apps that use the runtime.

Comment: My strong recommendation is for you to dump this architecture.

Comment: @CommonsWare There is a rock and a hardplace I could tell you about :(

Answer (score 0):

"android:process" and "android:taskAffinity" allows you to have different processes and affinities within the same package (application).

"android:multiprocess" simply means if you want to allow the activity to have a different process-id. This only works within the same app, not when the activity is started from a different a different package.

What are you exactly trying to do? If you want to share the same context and private files, you should use sharedUserId instead (you have to sign them using the same certificate as well).

Answer (score 0):

Try signing both apps with the same certificate. From http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html:

> You can also set android:process so that components of different applications run in the same process—provided that the applications share the same Linux user ID and are signed with the same certificates.

If you can't control Guest later on, you might be SOOL